# Generics method overriding with polymorphic this

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to do this:

```js
class A {
  static a: string = '';
  static m<T extends typeof A>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {
    this.a;
    return new this();
  }
}
class B extends A {
  static b: number = 5;
  static m<T extends typeof B>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {
    this.b + this.a;
    return new this();
  }
}
```

But that results in this error:

```
Class static side 'typeof B' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof A'.
  Types of property 'm' are incompatible.
    Type '<T extends typeof B>(this: T) => void' is not assignable to type '<T extends typeof A>(this: T) => void'.
      The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'typeof B'.
          Property 'b' is missing in type 'typeof A' but required in type 'typeof B'.ts(2417)
```

Which doesn't make sense to me because clearly calling B.m() will be sending a B type. Furthermore, B is a specialization so it should satisfy all of A, right?

Of course changing it to

```js
class B extends A {
  static b: number = 5;
  static m<T extends typeof A>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {
    this.b + this.a;
    return new this();
  }
}
```

Results in an error for `this.b`.

I can solve this by doing:

```js
class B extends A {
  static b: number = 5;
  static m<T extends typeof A>(this: T & typeof B): InstanceType<T> {
    this.b + this.a;
    return new this();
  }
}
```

But this seems extremely verbose and I don't want to have to force users of my library to be so verbose and remember such weird things.

Am I missing something? Is this a bug? Any better solutions?

Comment: Why are you using generics at all here?  Why not `static m(this: typeof A){}` and `static m(this: typeof B){}`?  Or, for that matter, why not just `static m(){}` for both... I'm pretty sure `this` inside of `B.m` will assume `this` has at least the properties of the `B` constructor.  Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oQC5nQS2NMAXGugE7YB2A5tALzQBE9A3CsVrtALYAUAlIq1ToAFtggA6MC1QBfJHNCQYAIWgBTAB7o15ACYx4yVBnZ4ARkXIBXTmbUla0AKzS2OPD35HU0EWPFm0ADUvqISUqxyckA)?

Comment: Good point, I want my return type to be based on who called it. Will update example.

Comment: When you say "who called it", you mean hypothetical subclasses of `A` and `B` that you haven't shown in your example?  If so, you're looking for something like static polymorphic `this` (which makes sense given your title) but as far as I know there's [no real support for that](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) that isn't a messy workaround.  Generics used as method parameters, including `this` parameters, seem to be contravariant, but really you always want `this `parameters to be treated as covariant (or maybe even bivariant).  I don't have a great answer for you here. 

Comment: Yeah I'm on that thread as ntucker...was hoping maybe someone here would have a better guess but it's starting to look unsolved. I hope this is work they can do to fix it tho.